# How to identify Bundle ID and App Store ID in React Native unpublished app

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm currently developing an unpublished React Native app. I am needing to access my Bundle ID and App Store ID for development, as I [plan on using Firebase Magic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth) as Auth on my application.

As part of this, I require the Bundle ID and App Store ID from my app, to put into the Firebase console.

I've had a Google and searched Stack Overflow, but can't find a recent answer for this.

The app is not registered with Apple in any way at the moment. I've not touched any details like this, and this is my first React Native app I'm developing.

So how do I access the app's Bundle ID and App Store ID, and know what it is? The app isn't ready to be published yet unsurprisingly, so I don't understand how I can put it on the App Store at this stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App Store id is optional you don't need that at the moment.

You can find your app bundle id in xCode -> Project Root -> General -> Bundle ID

[image]

I hope this help you out. You can modify your bundle id according to your project name.